# Eclipse plugin error: "commons-codec does not exist"

Tags: eclipse

Out of a sudden Eclispe (Neon.3) errors when compiling any project:

*Message*: `commons-codec does not exist` *Plugin*: `org.eclipse.jdt.core`

I updated all plugins - to no avail.

[edit: thanks to @greg-449 I add the more precise log message from `$workspace/.metadata/.log` ]:

`!MESSAGE Unable to merge Maven manifest: The JAR/ZIP file (~/git/elasticsearch/plugins/discovery-gce/build/precommit/thirdPartyAudit/thirdPartyAudit/META-INF/maven/commons-codec/commons-codec/pom.xml) seems corrupted, error: error in opening zip file`

Hm, not sure. I think the message above does not belong to originally mentioned Plugin-problem but only accidentially matched when searching for `commons-codec`. At least the line before in the logs doesn't match the proper entry - while this does:

`!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 969 2019-12-02 10:41:31.444
!MESSAGE commons-codec does not exist`

but it isn't more talkative than the error-message'at the top of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several fixes:

1. *Preferred fix*:
   if you are not already on the latest eclipse version, update eclipse (as @greg-449 pointed out, this could be a bug of older versions).
2. *Else try this workaround*:
   create a new workspace:
   `File->SwitchWorkspace->other->$newWorkspaceName`

When you go with 2., you may be a bit disappointed because all the projects have to be reimported and the appearance of eclipse is also resetted.

Comment: If there is a way to fix the old workspace I would be happy to let me know.

Comment: You could always try a version of Eclipse which isn't 7 (soon to be 8) releases out of date. Any bug fixes will only be in the newer releases. Also look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.